# Can't use sudo commands after removing the user password

Tags: password, password-recovery

I was searching for a way to disable sudo password promot , then I found a command to remove the user password `sudo passwd -d username` but after I wrote it and try to make `sudo` commands it asks for the password, i tried to put the old password and blank password but unfortunately it says  ***Sorry, try again***

What should I type or do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I tried to change the password again by `passwd` without `sudo` and it didn't ask me for old password then I put a new one.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted (click the green tick next to it) to clearly show the community that the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do that! :D